# insert the same string into multiple rows in a single column

Tags: r

I have an R data frame that looks like this :

[image: Image 1]

I would like to insert the same string into specific rows and into one column, like this (image 2):

[image: Image 2]

e.g. String 'zoo' into a single column 'groups' in only rows 1 ,3 and 6

Comment: When asking for help, it's easier if you include data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) rather than putting data inside images.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
df[df$RowNumber %in% c(1,3,6), "groups"] <- "zoo"
df

RowNumber groups
1         1    zoo
2         2   <NA>
3         3    zoo
4         4   <NA>
5         5   <NA>
6         6    zoo
7         7   <NA>
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(RowNumber=c(1:7), groups=rep(NA,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-using @Tim Biegeleisen's data, you could use the `ifelse` function to define the condition under which the values in column `groups`should change to `zoo`:

```
df$groups <- ifelse(df$RowNumber==1|df$RowNumber==3|df$RowNumber==6, "zoo", df$groups); df
  RowNumber groups
1         1    zoo
2         2   <NA>
3         3    zoo
4         4   <NA>
5         5   <NA>
6         6    zoo
7         7   <NA>
```